# Get value from array in json blob

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I am trying to get a value in second line of msg_values after colon:

```
{
    "txt": {
        "new": false,
        "msg": "Generating 'value'\nGenerated new value: +somestring12345=\n",
        "msg_values": [
            "Generating 'value'",
            "Generated new value: +somestring12345=",
            ""
        ]
    }
}
```

`jq -r '.[].msg_values[]' test.json` returns:

```
Generating 'value'
Generated new value: +somestring12345=
```

What I want is just a:
`+somestring12345=`

I've tried with select and map but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `index`, e.g. along the lines of:

```
.txt|.msg_values[1]| index(":") as $ix | .[1+$ix:]
```

or more defensively:

```
.txt|.msg_values[1]| (index(":") // empty) as $ix | .[1+$ix:]
```

Since it’s not clear how exactly you want to trim the value, I’ll leave that detail to you.

Comment: This seems to be working but I need to trim the leading [space]. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is using `sed` an option here?

```
jq -r '.[].msg_values[1]' test.json | sed -r "s/(.*):(.*)/\2/"
```

Comment: No, sorry for not mentioning that earlier. I've had this working with grep and cut.